# How do I find out change history of a line of code

Tags: git

`git blame` can be used to find out which commit modified, but I ran into a situation that it appears the whole file is copied from somewhere that I can't tell.

```
$ git blame a.c
c59f772b (a@google.com 2011-08-25 01:07:44 +0000   1)   #include <stdio.h>
c59f772b (a@google.com 2011-08-25 01:07:44 +0000   2)   
c59f772b (a@google.com 2011-08-25 01:07:44 +0000   3)   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
c59f772b (a@google.com 2011-08-25 01:07:44 +0000   4)       void *handle;
c59f772b (a@google.com 2011-08-25 01:07:44 +0000   5)       double (*cosine)(double);
...

$ git log c59f772b
commit c59f772bc273e65985236ba665f7a88492a33235
Author: a@google.com
Date:   Thu Aug 25 01:07:44 2011 +0000

    Cloning a bunch of stuff from the another repository
    No changes, as is.
```

This commit is just about copying the code. I still don't know which and who actually wrote this code.

Can I have a list for change history of code or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glance at the power that is git :)

```
git blame -M -C -C -C -w
```

from `git help blame`:

> `-C`
>
> In addition to -M, detect lines moved or copied from other files that were modified in the same commit. This is useful when you
>   reorganize your program and move code around across files. When this
>   option is given twice, the command additionally looks for copies from
>   other files in the commit that creates the file. When this option is
>   given three times, the command additionally looks for copies from
>   other files in any commit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no good way because you just copy the file from another palce and commit it.

If you know those class, you can use git commit --author authorname

will help you print all of related commits.

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the changes to a single file, and see the file name changes do the following:

```
git log --stat --follow -- <filename>
```

Now to blame the file from that previous point you'll have to specify the old file name that may not exist anymore.

```
git blame <hash_before_move> -- <old_file_name>
```